# Capturing mousewheel zoom in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, dom-events, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have a map in OpenLayers that has a number of layers with Markers. Each time the user zooms the map I call a function that groups overlapping markers. This works just fine when zooming using the normal zoom buttons, but I also want to call this function when a user zooms using the mouse wheel.

I guess I have to use the `OpenLayers.Handler.MouseWheel` to capture this event, but I don't know how. Does anyone have an example for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use map's `zoomend` event that fires every time user zooms in or out no matter how user did it (buttons, double click or mouse scroll).

The code should look like this:

```
map.events.on({ "zoomend": function(){
    //Do whatever you need to do here
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest version of Openlayers v6.5.0.
I got it worked

```
this.map = new Map({
            controls: [],
            interactions: defaultInteractions({
                shiftDragZoom: false,
                doubleClickZoom: false,
                pinchRotate: false,
                mouseWheelZoom: false,
            }).extend([
                new MouseWheelZoom({
                    condition: platformModifierKeyOnly,
                    handleEvent: (event) => {
                        if (event.type !== "wheel") return;

                        if (event.originalEvent.deltaY <= -3) {
                            //mouse wheel up
                        } else {
                            //mouse wheel down
                        }
                    },
                }),
            ]),
            target: "map",
            layers,
        });
```